# Run Macro every time filter is on

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that runs when any cell is changed, and I want to sum only the shown cells, so if someone filters the sheet the macro will run and sum just the visible cells.

I found the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` function but I can't manage to make it work.

My idea of the code is something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Rcells As Range
    Dim sum as Double
    sum = 0
    For each Rcells In Range("A5:A65536").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    sum = sum + Rcells.Value
    Next Rcells
    Sheets("aSheet").Range("B1").Value = sum
End Sub
```

I managed to sum just the visible cells but it does not run automatically.

Why is it not working?

Comment: Just a curious question, do you really have 65536 rows of data?

Comment: This `Dim i, fin As Integer` doesn't do what you think it does!

Comment: thanks, I know the don't do anyting, I just forgot to delate them. I dont have 65536, just to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two key two steps from my article [Trapping a change to a filtered list with VBA](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2773-Trapping-a-change-to-a-filtered-list-with-VBA.html) which includes detailed instructions and a sample fle:

1. A second *dummy* WorkSheet is added with a single `SUBTOTAL` formula in `A1` pointing back to the range being filtered on the main sheet (i.e. the range you want to capture the filter on).
2. A `Worksheet_Calculate()` Event is added to the *dummy* WorkSheet, this Event fires when the `SUBTOTAL` formula updates when the filter is changed on your main sheet.

Comment: First of all I am a dummy in VBA so dont get me serious. I am not sure if I didn't understand your code o what, but, I tried your code and I dont know how it triggers the "sum", anyway I appreciete everything.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the subtotal function. enter =subtotal(
then hit the fx to understand how it works.

Comment: thanks. now the problem is to run automatically the macro when I filter.

Comment: Why can't you just use the formula?